# Remove label section from paper-textarea

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

I'd like to remove the extra space that the label takes up in a polymer text-area. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--paper-input-container-label   
--paper-input-container-label-focus 
--paper-input-container-label-floating
```

These are three `mixins` that can be applied to `label` in paper-text-area. You can use these to style label or hide it as per your need

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are some default margin on padding. Without code it's hard to say.